# Настройка teredo. Получить IPv6

Tags: c#, windows, ipv6

У меня есть сервер и клиент. Задача установить соединение по протоколу IPv6 при помощи teredo (либо другой технологии).

В локальной сети все работает (клиент и сервер подключены к одному wi-fi модему). Как получить IPv6 для работы в интернете?

P.S.
При выполнении пару тестов выявилось:
[image: teredo]
[image: ipconfig]